# adding images by using function in dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, html

I've a homework about html and javascript and I have done somethings butIi didnt managed to work

This is what school gave me:

"You will create a file namely hw3_2.html that contains a javascript function taking an
input from user and displaying two images. There is a dropdown list in this page and a user
can select one of the three images. The image that the user selected is displayed as first
image. When the user makes this selection, a random number is generated between 1 - 3 and
the corresponding image is displayed as second image. Then a message will also be displayed
whether these two images are same or different. The user interface of the web page is shown
below. You may use photos of your hometown instead of the images of Eskisehir."

Here is what I've done so far:
can  you help me?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    var obj=document.getElementById("photo");

    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=x;

    var y=obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].id;

function image(){

    function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
    var img    = document.createElement("img");
    img.src    = src;
    img.width  = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.alt    = alt;



    }
    var p1=new show_image('eskisehir1.png', 276, 110,'Eskisehir1');
    var p2=new show_image('eskisehir2.png', 276, 110,'Eskisehir2');
    var p3=new show_image('eskisehir3.png', 276, 110,'Eskisehir3');

    if(y==x ){

       if(y==1)
          {document.body.appendChild(p1);}
       else if(y==2)
          {document.body.appendChild(p2);}
       else
         {document.body.appendChild(p3);}
        }

    else // i couldnt fill this , 

    }
   }     

</script>
</head>
<body>
< !-- do i need to add more attibute? -->
Photos:<select id="photo" onchange="getRandomInt(1,3);">
           <option value="1" >eskisehir1</option>
           <option value="2" >eskisehir2</option>
           <option value="3" >eskisehir3</option>
       </select >

 <p id="para"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

maybe i made lots of mistakes but i wanna learn this

Comment: What will `new show_image(`…`)` return?

Comment: i think it is a object method

Comment: Also, a few minor things: use `value` instead of `id` on your `<option>` tags. An number-only `id` is invalid. And then you can check the value with `var y=obj.value` which is much easier. You also have an excess `>` at your second option.

Comment: Yes, `new show_image()` will create a new object, but this object is empty and it is not your image element. You still need something in your `show_image` function so that `document.body.appendChild(p1)` makes sense at all. Otherwise `p1` is an empty object.

Comment: i cannot understandby saying "new show_image() " is empty ,it has ost of properties

Comment: Another question: why did you write `new show_image()` instead of simply `show_image()`? Empty means that the `new` operator creates an object based on the variables and properties inside a function; however the object that you create contains a “private” reference to the created image element. You cannot access it from outside the function. The object doesn’t contain a “public” property that points to the element.

Comment: The function does contain the variable `img` but the object you create does not contain it as a property.

Comment: I don’t know how your teacher expects this to be done, but I would remove the `new` operators. You don’t need a _function instance_ object here. You need the image element itself and you can get that by ***returning*** it in the function.

Comment: i think ,i started understand you but stliil i dont know where i need to fix

Comment: because iim new at this

Comment: correct so errors and reformat code

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, well, let's check your code.

First, your way of getting the select value works, but it's much simpler to just do `obj.value`, to get the current value of the select box (and since you're executing this function `onchange`, that'll give you the value the user just selected).

Second, your `show_image` function is alright, it does in fact create an image and sets attributes to it, but it doesn't return anything, nor does it set any properties that will be made available with the `new` operator (read more on `new` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) and [here](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/12/the-new-keyword-in-javascript/)). It's simpler to just return the created image, rather than make an object with the `new` keyword, so you should just do that.

Finally, you are creating all the possible images at once, but from what I understand, you only need two. One with the selected value, and the other with a random number. I think that instead of creating them all and dropping some `if`s in there, you should just create the two that are needed, and compare whether they are the same or not, and append them. Also, the way you are doing things with your if logic, only one image will get appended, and not two; I don't see where you are appending the selected image to the document.

**I made this jsFiddle for you:**

http://jsfiddle.net/xvvt3j8d/7/

Notice the change in structure. This code must come after the select box markup, or if you really want it in your document's head, inside of a `window.onload` event. The same thing applies if you want to include this code from an external `.js` file.

And I made all the changes I mentioned you should do. Here's **the code with comments**:

```
// Identify the select box, the 'dialog' box, and the images container.
var selectBox = document.getElementById('photo'),
    imagesContainer = document.getElementById('imagesContainer'),
    dialog = document.getElementById('dialog');

// This will append two images and compare whether they are the same.

function getImages() {

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // This is multiple variable syntax, it uses commas. It is sometimes nice, to tidy up things.
    // * selectBox.value returns the current value of the selectBox
    // * randomNumber stores whatever getRandomInt returns (now a separate function)
    // * randomImage stores what createImage returns, with the given params (an image).
    //   Notice I used concatenation of strings/numbers, since all images are named similarly.
    // * Equality uses the ternary operator to determine if the selectValue and randomNumber are equal.
    //   This way of doing logic may be new to you. Look up the ternary operator in Google. It's handy.

    var selectValue = selectBox.value,
        randomNumber = getRandomInt(1, 3),
        randomImage = createImage('eskisehir' + randomNumber + '.png', 276, 110, 'Eskisehir' + randomNumber),
        equality = selectValue == randomNumber ? 'equal' : 'not equal';

    // Now it's a separate function. I think this makes things more organized.
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    // Renamed show_image to createImage.
    function createImage(src, width, height, alt) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = src;
        img.width = width;
        img.height = height;
        img.alt = alt;
        // This is important! Your function now returns the image element stored in img.
        // If you don't do this, whenever you call this func, it will return undefined,
        // and the img var won't be available outside of this function.
        return img;
    }
    // Append both of the images and change the dialog to say whether they are the same or not.
    // Also, 'clean' the contents of the images container each time,
    // and append the new images to it.
    imagesContainer.innerHTML = '';
    imagesContainer.appendChild(createImage('eskisehir' + selectValue + '.png', 276, 110, 'Eskisehir' + selectValue));
    imagesContainer.appendChild(randomImage);
    dialog.innerHTML = 'The images are ' + equality;
}
// Assign getImages to the onchange event of the select box.
selectBox.onchange = getImages;
```

Comment: thank you so much , it's  almost done but i need some little thing .The thing is when i select an option ,the previous images must be removed and there should be two new images

Comment: @Sena Sure, of course, in order to achieve that, it's easiest to just make a container, append the images to it, and remove the contents each time new images are to be inserted. I've updated the code. Hope it works for you. My code is not perfect, and I'm not a great programmer, but take a look into how I ordered things so you get an idea of how to write more organized code. Learn from this. Keep learning. And I'm glad I could help.